# how to add/remove a class from a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap tabs and I have four of them. I want them to have a different color each which should change when the user clicks on them, bootstrap has the "active" class, but it's not working because I'm using diffent color for each tab, so I decided to use a jquery function to add a class when the user clicks on a tab, but I don't know how to remove the class when a user clicks on a different one.

Is there a way to pass two values to a function, one value is from one link o the other from a another link, so when I click cars, I wat to remove the class from trucks and when I click on trucks remove the class from cars

HTML

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li class="active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#link2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#link3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" id="cars">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#link4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" id="trucks" >Link 3</a></li>
          </ul>
```

CSS

```
#cars
{
    color: #FFF; 
    background: #ec7501;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ec7501 1%, #c46200 56%, #ec7501 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#ec7501), color-stop(56%,#c46200), color-stop(100%,#ec7501));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ec7501 1%,#c46200 56%,#ec7501 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ec7501 1%,#c46200 56%,#ec7501 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ec7501 1%,#c46200 56%,#ec7501 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ec7501 1%,#c46200 56%,#ec7501 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ec7501', endColorstr='#ec7501',GradientType=0 );
    border-top: 2px solid #de9d5b;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #a64800;
    border-top-left-radius: 12px;
    border-top-right-radius: 12px;
}

.activeTab
{
    color:#000 !important;
    background:#FFF !important;
}
```

JS
edits based on Ed Cottrell comments,

```
('#cars, #trucks').on('click', function() {
    changeColor($(this)); // passes the element itself
});

function changeColor($elem)
{
    $('.activeTab').removeClass('activeTab'); // remove the class from elements that have it
    $elem.addClass('activeTab');
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/7xcLsqgd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$(selector).removeClass(class)`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/). Also, you shouldn't be using inline `onclick` triggers with jQuery; use dynamic bindings instead.

Example:

```
$('#cars').on('click', function() {
    changeColor('cars');
});

$('#some_other_tab').on('click', function() {
    $('.activeTab').removeClass('activeTab'); // remove the class from elements that have it
    doSomethingElse();
});
```

**Edit:** Based on your comments, you want something like this:

```
$('#cars, #trucks').on('click', function() {
    changeColor($(this).prop('id')); // passes the id of the element receiving the click
});

function changeColor(id)
{
    $('.activeTab').removeClass('activeTab'); // remove the class from elements that have it
    $('#' + id).addClass('activeTab');
}
```

Even simpler, skip the id stuff:

```
$('#cars, #trucks').on('click', function() {
    changeColor($(this)); // passes the element itself
});

function changeColor($elem)
{
    $('.activeTab').removeClass('activeTab'); // remove the class from elements that have it
    $elem.addClass('activeTab');
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass two values to a function, one value is from one link o the other from a nother link, so when I click cars, I wat to remove the class from trucks and when I click on trucks remove the class from cars

Comment: So it will work when I either I click on cars or trucks and to remove the class, I have to add the revoceClass syntax????

Comment: I added an explanation of how to do that, too. Just remove it from whatever element has it, then add it to the new active element.

Comment: I updated my question, look clean the code, but for some reason is not working :/

Comment: It works fine; [see this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/e2zczcmw/). It's hard to tell that it's working with your CSS because you are setting the background to white.  Also, you have only applied the action to two of the links. If you want to apply it to others, include them in the selector in `$(...).on(...)` or use a class or other selector (like `.nav-tabs li`) to make them active, as well. For example, `$('.nav-tabs li').on(...)`;

Comment: thank you, I will try why they are not working on my page, but thanks you alot for you help

Comment: Glad to help out! Good luck, and always feel free to post a new question if you run into more problems.